# through an iOS app how to run a dmg file which is executable from the terminal? I'm looking for something similar to Java's Runtime exec

Tags: python, ios, objective-c

I've never worked with iOS, and I'm trying to get this done for someone else. The person wants to integrate my software (basically an algorithm that takes images, and outputs processed images) within their app. This algorithm of mine is written in python and it uses openCV. I've managed to create a dmg out of the python file so that when I give it to the person for usage on their mac, they don't have to install all the libraries before executing the dmg through their terminal.

Also, for the mac application, the standalone is written in Java, and I'm able to execute the dmg file using [runtime exec](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_exec.htm) is there anything similar in Objective C? How do I go about giving the person the algorithm for iOS packaged in a way such that they don't have to install all the libraries before using it?

Comment: Can't be done. There's no way to run Java on iOS.

Comment: That's far from what I asked. I don't want to run java on iOS I basically want to run python code, but I want to package it first (in a format like dmg or exe) so that all the libraries required by the python code don't have to be installed

Comment: You are asking how to run a dmg (that contains a Java app) under iOS, correct? If not, then clarify your question.

Comment: The dmg contains python code. Please refer to my edited comment above yours. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Then you should update your question (and its tags) to make it clear that you wish to run a Python app under iOS. Right now it's really confusing since you talk about Java and tag the question with Swift.

Comment: What tags do you recommend? I'm quite ignorant about the required tags for this question, since I haven't had the chance to work with iOS at all

Comment: How about iOS and python?

Comment: No, you didn't clarify your question.

Comment: I think it wasn't clear just to you. Can you point me to where I say it's the java code that I want to run on iOS.  I'll be happy to edit. I'm just not sure what part of the question isn't very clear. I basically want to run a dmg made out of python code through objective-c. The way I do it in java is using runtime exec. That's what I meant.